# Function of だけ of だけまだ幸運だった?

Tags: particle-だけ

> あんな状況の中、あんな文面で士道からお誘いがあったなら、普通の女子であれば警戒するに決まっている。わざわざ馬鹿正直に一人で待ち合わせ場所に来ようとは思わないだろう。すっぽかされなかった**だけ**まだ幸運だったかもしれなかった。

Context: In the name of 士道, a letter was sent to 亜衣, one of 士道’s classmates, telling her (亜衣) to go alone to meet 士道 in a cafe. But it turned out that 亜衣 went there in company with her friends.

Hi. Is function of the だけ in bold 範囲を限定する, as in「学校だけでなく家庭での指導も大切だ」?

And can I think the だけまだ幸運だった is a variant of the idiom だけまだましだった?

And why isn’t だけで used here?

By the way, does the だけ in the following quote have the same function as the first example?

> 何しろ買い物から帰ってきたら、出かける前に見ていた街とは別の光景が広がっていたというのである。その場にへたり込んでしまわない**だけ**、折紙はまだ幾分落ち着いているのかもしれなかった。

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

だけ(まだ)まし is not a fixed idiom. The general form is: `[small good thing] + だけ + [favorable conclusion]`.

- 生きているだけ運がよかった。
  It was lucky that I survived at least.
- 殺されなかっただけありがたいと思え。
  You must be thankful just for not being killed.
- サーバーが全停止しなかっただけ、アラートには意味があったと思う。
  I think the alert was meaningful only because the servers weren't completely shut down.
- すっぽかされなかっただけまだ幸運だったかもしれなかった。
  I may have been fortunate that I was at least not ignored.

だけ primarily means "only", but it also means "as much as" or "to such-and-such extent", as in できるだけ頑張る and 食べたら食べただけ太る. So this `A + だけ + B` construction can be understood as "One can say B to the extent that A" or "One can at least say B just because of A".